# Request works on Postman, but is received as 'undefined' by FETCH

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman

Having trouble sending information to the backend. Currently, I have the following `fetch` function in my frontend:

```
function appending() {
        console.log('in Appending');
        console.log('formInfo', formInfo);
        console.log('formInfofrom', formInfo.from)
        
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/add-transaction', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: {
                from: formInfo.from,
                to: formInfo.to,
                amount: formInfo.amount,
                fee: formInfo.fee
            }
        }).then((backendResponse) => {
            if(backendResponse.ok)
                return backendResponse.json();
        }).then((theJSON) => {
            // ERROR: 1 - not enough funds
            // ERROR: 0 - no errors
            console.log('theJSON: ', theJSON);
            console.log('Error is: ', theJSON.error);

            if(theJSON.error === 1) {
                console.log('Insufficient')
                setBackendError("insufficient");
            }
            else if (theJSON.error === 0) {
                console.log("Sufficient funds")
                setBackendError("sufficient")
            }
            else {
                console.log("Mongo error")
                setBackendError("mongo");
            }

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('error is', error);
        })
    }
```

`formInfo` is a JSON object which has 4 key/value pairs, the `from` key, `to` key, `amount` and `fee`:

```
const formInfo = { "from": "", "to": "", "amount": "", "fee":"" };
```

When I check the console after sending a transaction, I see the following:

[image: formInfo from console]

which tells me that it's valid. When I check the backend, however, I see the result of `req.body.from` as `undefined` in the console:

[image: requestFrom]

The code for this route is as follows:

```
app.post('/add-transaction', (req, res) => {
        
    console.log('requestFrom', req.body.from);

        blockModel.find({ $or: [{ from: req.body.from }, { to: req.body.from }, { miner: req.body.from }] }).then((blocks) => {
            if (!blocks.length) {
                yakhicoin.addBlock(new Block("system", req.body.from, 1000, 0, "null", 0));
                const newblock = new blockModel(yakhicoin.getLatestBlock());
                newblock.save();
            }
            let balance = 0;
            for (const block of blocks) {
                if (block.from == req.body.from) {balance -= (block.amount + block.fee);}
                if (block.to == req.body.from) {balance += block.amount;}
                if (block.miner == req.body.from) {balance += (block.fee + block.reward);}
            }
            if (req.body.amount <= balance || (!blocks.length && req.body.amount <= 1000)) {
                const formData = {
                    "from": req.body.from,
                    "to": req.body.to,
                    "amount": req.body.amount,
                    "fee": req.body.fee
                }
                const newtransaction = new transactionModel(formData);
                newtransaction
                    .save() //  Promise
                    .then( //resolved...
                        (success) => {
                            res.send({"transaction" : success, "error" : 0});
                        }
                    )
                    .catch( //rejected...
                        (error) => {
                            res.send({"error" : error});
                        }
                    );
            }
            else
                res.json({"error" : 1})
        })
})
```

When I use the same route in POSTMAN, everything works fine:
[image: transaction from POSTMAN]

With the following headers:

[image: POSTMAN headers]

I can't see why this error occurs, no matter how often I check it. Why does `formInfo` suddenly get received as undefined, when it exists right before sending? I also have `cors()` enabled. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should be using the "network" tab in your dev tools to debug the request, not the "console" tab.  If the request in the "network" tab matches the request in postman, you should see the same behavior server side.

Comment: Hello! I just checked the Network tab, it says Payload has `[object Object]: `, any idea how to deal with this? https://imgur.com/LsmPz4q

Comment: Check the "content-type" header in your browser request.  Make sure it matches what's in postman.

Comment: Hello, I did that, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Please provide all code, errors, data, etc. as text, not as pictures of text. See [ask], where it says, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! How would I post POSTMAN as text though? :(

Comment: Show the raw headers and body (there is a raw radio button you can switch to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that the body encoding is different in the browser example from the postman example.

The body in your post request should be a string (example below), when using the content-type you are currently using.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'from=xxxxx&to=yyyyyy....etc'
  })
```

Or you can change the content-type and stringify the object.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
    Content-Type: 'application/json',
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formInfo)
})
```

Comment: Hello, this fixed it, it really was just stringify!! Thank you :)